# Select LUIS model by luisRecognizer based on user' prefer locale in Version#4 node js

Tags: botframework

```
I have used couple of LUIS model in bot framework v#3 Node js based on user preferred locale without using the text translator api. Now I would like to implement same thing in version#4 as part of migration.

Below is code snippet written in version#3.

    var many_language_recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer({
      'en': englishModel || process.env.EN_LUIS,
      'es': spanishModel || process.env.ES_LUIS,
      'fr': frenchModel || process.env.FR_LUIS
    });

    bot.recognizer(many_language_recognizer);
```

I would like to implement above version#3 code snippet in v#4. Please help me out. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply need to:

1. Choose a locale
2. Select LUIS model credentials based off of chosen locale
3. Create `LuisRecognizer` passing in the credentials

---

**.env**

So in your .env you might have multiple LUIS credentials (as you should create different LUIS models for different languages)

```
EsLuisAppId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
EsLuisAPIKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
EsLuisAPIHostName=yourEsHostname

DeLuisAppId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
DeLuisAPIKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DeLuisAPIHostName=yourDeHostname
```

**In Your Bot**

You would have some logic to select the right set of credentials based off of the locale.

```js
if (locale == 'es-es') {
    luisApplication = {
        applicationId: process.env.EsLuisAppId,
        endpointKey: process.env.EsLuisAPIKey,
        endpoint: `https://${ process.env.EsLuisAPIHostName }.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`
    };
}

if (locale == 'de-de') {
    luisApplication = {
        applicationId: process.env.DeLuisAppId,
        endpointKey: process.env.DeLuisAPIKey,
        endpoint: `https://${ process.env.DeLuisAPIHostName }.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`
    };
}
```

Note: your logic matching locale to correct LUIS credential might be different (perhaps you'd prefer switch statement, etc.)

Then once you set your `luisApplication` credentials, create your `LuisRecognizer`

`const recognizer = new LuisRecognizer(luisApplication);`

---

**Example of LUIS in Action in V4**

If you'd like an example of LUIS in action in v4, I'd  recommend checking out the [14.nlp-with-dispatch](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/14.nlp-with-dispatch) sample in the botbuilder-samples repo.

It doesn't mess with different locales, but at least you can see how the LUIS recognizer is used in an up-to-date bot.

---

**What You Need to Decide: Where to Get the Locale**

So what's up to you is where you decide to get the locale.
You can check out the unit tests in [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/1106/files#diff-1537ea2e9dc014213b0d493e3b6c3cd1R309) regarding internationalization in `NumberPrompts`, a different feature in V4 bots, for some ideas (e.g. getting locale from activity, having a default locale, making the dialog require a locale, etc.)